# Insertion caret color on windows

Tags: front-end

Where is the option to change the insertion caret (text cursor) color? When using a dark stylesheet like ReverseColor, I get a dark cursor that's almost invisible against the background. I can't find where to change the color though.

Following [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1193315?sortMsg=Recent), I can change the color of the cursor in other contexts, but it isn't the primary one.

I'm on Windows 10, using Mathematica 12.3, but I don't remember having had this problem on my Mac.

Comment: You need to adjust the Windows Mouse settings.

Comment: I'm pretty certain they are actually referring to the insertion point caret.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @ihojnicki, yes that's what I meant. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bug was fixed in 12.3.1, which I think you can grab from the portal.

Comment: Can you please provide the release id of your installation of `12.3.1` by running, `AssociationMap[
 SystemInformation[#, "ReleaseID"] &, {"Kernel", "FrontEnd"}]`.

Comment: Yep, that was it! It was a bug and I had 12.3.0 installed. Should I do anything (tag, delete) with this question in light of that?

Comment: @Jaffe42 it is more useful to remain, I think